# How to modify Card-IO manual entry screen

Tags: android, paypal, credit-card, card.io

I want to modify Card.IO **manual entry screen** and place a button on that screen.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

The source code to card.io is available ([Android repo](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source), [iOS repo](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source)). So you are welcome to fork the relevant repo and make any changes you desire.

Comment: I see there is MIT license involved. Is it safe in terms of Legal issues to modify the code and using it for Commercial Purpose? 

Also Could you please let me know I need to include whole source repo in my project to do any modification or can I include selective files in my project and change it.